# Navbar small box error on left hand side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello guys im newish to bootstrap and html and im having a problem when i set up my navbar its showing a small box on the left hand side of my screen.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YUVL.png)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <title>VENDER</title>

   <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

   <body>

   <!-- STYLE -->
   <style>   
   body {
   background-color: white;
   }
   </style>

    <!-- INFO -->
    <div class="top-container-fluid"> 
    <div class="row">
    <p class="headertext"><b>  TEXT HERE! </B></p>
    </div>
    </div>



    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name Site</a>        
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-
    target=".navHeaderCollapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our [SO Question Checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you misspelled a class name.

The correct class name is `navbar-toggler` and not "navbar-toggle".

Also, you don't need any `<span class="icon-bar"></span>` because that's all built-in in Bootstrap 4.

Use the following code as an example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```